# Loop list in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So I have one parameter in Cloudformation with a type of `List<String>`

The values I'm passing are: `[0,1,2,3,4]`

What I want to get is something along the lines of:

`submission_0 submission_1 submission_2 submission_3 etc..`

This is what I've tried so far:

`!Join [" submission_", !Ref queueIdList]`

And this is the output:

`[0 submission_1 submission_2 submission_3 submission_4]`

The output should not contain `[ ]` and the first submission is missing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a nested join:

```
!Join ['', ['submission_', !Join [' submission_', !Ref queueIdList]]
```

The `[ ]` are probably because you are including them in your input. Try `0,1,2,3,4` as the parameter value